# How to delete some records using query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two tables equipment and obj_app and using ACCESS 2010. Where one equipment.id_app corresponds to many obj_app.id_app. I've used this query:

```
SELECT OBJ_APP.ID_APP
FROM equipment   
LEFT OUTER JOIN  OBJ_APP 
ON OBJ_APP.ID_APP = equipment.ID_APP
WHERE OBJ_APP.ID_APP IS NULL
```

How to delete these records?

Comment: Delete the records from what table? Equipment, Obj_App or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the JOIN, you are simply returning a bunch of NULLs since that is your WHERE criteria and the JOIN mechanism.

```
DELETE * FROM equipment e WHERE e.ID_APP IS NULL
DELETE * FROM OBJ_APP o WHERE o.ID_APP IS NULL
```